# Digital Signature is not valid

Tags: email, certificate, certificate-authority, cryptography, smime

I recently received a digital signed email from a friend and the certificate is issued by COMODO RSA Client Authentication and Secure Email. My problem is the thunderbird detect it as a "Not Valid Signature"

[image: Here's the pic]

I double checked the CA Authorities on thunderbird and it is already trusted, now I can't reply an encrypted and digitally signed email because of this problem. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `COMODO RSA Client Authentication and Secure Email` CA is not installed in thunderbird.

You may need to download the certificate and install in the thunderbird. I suspect, the talk is about the certificate provided here: https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1148/106/comodosha256clientauthenticationandsecureemailca

In Thumberbird, go to `Options -> Advanced -> View Certificates`. In the certificate store view, click on Import and select the CA certificate. When prompted select the `Trust this CA to identify email users` option. After this operation, email signature should be successfully validated.

Comment: The certificate is already trusted, I don't why it doesn't work. I installed a different client and it works perfectly fine.